# how to sort the Dates in array list in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

i have several files named in dated format(dd/mm/yyyy) .i have to collect them and sort in arraylist ? any suggestion ...i did like this

```
Dim filepath As String = FileStr
Dim directoryPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)
Dim arrayList As New System.Collections.ArrayList()
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)
 arrayList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
Next
arrayList.Sort()
```

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** a file named `29/06/2015.txt` is not valid on **Windows**. the following code has been tested using the following formats: `yyyy-mm-dd`,`yyyy-dd-mm`,...

Would the following implentation not work? This uses a [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) however instead of your `arraylist`.

```
Dim filepath As String = FileStr
Dim directoryPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)
Dim myFileList As New List(Of String)
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)
    'Add only dates to the list
    If (IsDate(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))) Then
        myFileList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
    End If
Next
myFileList.OrderByDescending(Function(x) CType(x, DateTime))
```

Use [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) Or [OrderBydescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx) to change the direction of sorting

---

If the `Arraylist` is mandatory then you still can change the output you can easily create an `ArrayList from a List` as follows.

```
Dim arr As New ArrayList(myFileList)
```

Comment: then what about different  months ?

Comment: if the format is dd/mm/yyyy then the ordering should be fine for Days-Months-Years.

Comment: `IsDate`is just a standard framework method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: My bad, made a typo. Code has been altered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81840/discussion-between-satyajit-and-user999999).